# Windows 7 freezes when accessing spanned volume

Tags: windows-7

So I made a data storage box with a collection of old hard drives and put Windows 7 on it for ease of use.

I used the disk tool in Windows 7 to create a single spanned volume with 4 IDE drives and two SATA drives with a total space of 1.18TB. I can write to this disk fine, and transferred a full TB of data to it, no issues.

While accessing the data(streaming .mkv files over a wired home network)the computer started to freeze up, randomly.

After one freeze, it wouldn't restart properly so I did a "Recovery". This made the spanned drive disappear.

I disconnected the two SATA drives and connected them to a second SATA controller on the same motherboard and restarted, which restored the spanned volume.

At this point, I removed ALL data from the spanned volume and ran a checkdisk on it with "fix errors" enabled. No errors were found...

From what I've read, it may be a flakey controller, any advice on how to better find the underlying problem than "hoping" its a flakey controller and abandoning the motherboard ?

The motherboard is an old MSI KT6 Delta with an Athlon 2300 CPU and 2GB of DDR400 RAM, tested for errors and found to be working.

Comment: it might be a flaky controller but yiou might want to try to re-create the span if that doesnt work its a controller issue

Comment: Can you explain further why re-creating the span would help?

Comment: @Jggreenblatt you have 11 answers so far, most of which are deleted, many downvoted and none upvoted. I highly recommend that you read the [How to Answer](http://superuser.com/questions/how-to-answer) page and concentrate on producing higher quality answers from here on, otherwise you may find yourself blocked from further participation by the system or a moderator.

Answer (score 0):

Windows spanned volumes are unfortunately inherently flaky.  Also, many times I have seen bad SATA cables and power connectors.  If you're wanting to run Windows, try swapping the SATA cables and SATA power connectors to see if you have more luck.

Honestly though, spanned volumes are a headache, and it sounds like you may benefit more by turning this box into a NAS device.  I recommend unRAID or FreeNAS.

Don't be worried about them being difficult, they both have large followings and GUI's.  (and they will combine a bunch of mismatched disks into a large one, i.e. drobo but cheap!)